# RestKit mapping: how to GET multiple root objects

Tags: ios, restkit

I need to GET multiple root objects with RestKit. JSON from server looks like this:

```
{
  "articles" : [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
  "counters_for_pagination": {"page": 1, "total": 250, "per_page": 5} 
}
```

Do I have to create intermediate class `PaginatedResults` which will hold `NSArray` of objects of type `Article` and `NSDictionary` with counters?

I'd like to get:

1. an array of `Article` objects which I will show in a `UITableView`
2. an `NSDictionary` of counters - for pagination.

Is RestKit able to return `NSDictionary` of 2 different objects as a `*result` or is it always returning an array?

Comment: How do you want to store it? Show at least that, and preferably what mappings you have tried. You don't 'need' an intermediate class.

Comment: I didn't try any mappings yet because I don't even know how to start with this type of mapping. In "success" callback I'd like to get: 1) array of 'Article' objects which I will show in UITableView 2) NSDictionary of counters - for pagination. Is RestKit able to return NSDictionary of 2 different objects as a `*result` or is it always returning an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, RestKit can do that. You need:

1. 2 object mappings, 1 linking to `Article` and the other to `NSMutableDictionary`
2. 2 response descriptors, 1 with keypath `articles` and the other `counters_for_pagination`

Once you have that setup, the mapping result dictionary will contain 2 keys which match the key paths in your response descriptors so that you can access your 2 different types of information.

(in effect, the mapping results is your intermediate class)

Comment: +1 Many thanks for your answer, I will try it now! I will accept it later if everything works fine.

Comment: are you author of RestKit?

Comment: Nope, Blake Watters is the (primary) author. I just like it.